# I'm setting up ActiveRecords and I can't name a field an integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class CreateOrderSheets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :order_sheets do |t|
        t.integer :155080
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I'm setting up ActiveRecords and I can't name a field an integer?

Comment: Why would you want to name your table column 155080?

Comment: Well I'm not labeling my table the integer. My table is labeled "order_sheets", but when I set up my form I want the "155080" to be what submits to my database along with the quantity entered in the field.

Answer (score 1):

If you use integer this way:

```
def change
    create_table :order_sheets do |t|
      t.integer :155080
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
end
```

It will give an error of **syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END**

All column fields must be **String** type.

For number as COLUMN_NAME, use:

```
def change
    create_table :order_sheets do |t|
      t.integer "155080"
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
end
```

Let say, Rails Migration read **:title** as **"title".**

Answer (score 0):

replace `t.integer :155080` into `t.integer "155080"`

It might help!

Comment: `to.integer "155080"` are you sure ?